# jmeter -not adding authorization header to all http requests

Tags: http, jmeter, header, authorization

i have a fairly simple testplan with following steps recorded

- Thread Group
- Recording Controller
- ```
    HTTP Authorization manager
  ```
- ```
    GET https://xxxx/user/login
  ```
- ```
    GET https://xxxx/accounts/list
  ```
- ```
    GET https://xxxx/user/settings
  ```
- ```
    GET https://xxxx/partners/list
  ```
- ```
    GET https://xxxx/user/logout
  ```

When i run this, i see jmeter adding the authorization header in the first user/login request and server responds with 200 OK. This is OK

i extract the session token from the login response and put it as a variable into the subsequent http requests.

jmeter is not adding the authorization header in the subsequent accounts/list request - this is OK

but then jmeter is adding the authorization header into the subsequent user/settings request - this is not needed as it defeats the purpose of sending the session token.

Again jmeter is not sending the auth token in partners/list but is sending it again in user/logout request.

So question is how jmeter determines when to add the auth header and when not?

The desired behaviour i want is for jmeter to send the auth header in the first user/login request but not in any of the subsequent http requests.

Any pointers appreciated.

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

HTTP Authorization Manager will add [Authorization](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Authorization) header to all the HTTP Request samplers **it its scope**, if you place it at the same level with the HTTP Request samplers - it will add the header to **all of them**.

If you need to apply the HTTP Authorization Manager to 1st sampler only - move it to be the child of the first sampler.

[image]

More information: [JMeter Scoping Rules - The Ultimate Guide](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/jmeter-scoping-rules-the-ultimate-guide)

Answer (score 0):

Recording any scenario adds up the Header Manager in all the Http requests.

You are doing it in correct way, however still you have to make few changes in your scripts to run seamlessly.

1. Delete all the subsequent Header Manager under the accounts/list,user/settings,partners/list & logout.
2. Post the Login Request > extract the session > Add a Header Manager after Login request and pass the session there.
3. All the further request should be in the same thread so that the session get passed to each request.

Also while recording there are multiple requests that gets captured and for each scenario Jmeter maintains the session under Header Manager, hence this should never be the case that one request is getting the session while others not.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the answer that helps.

What i did and worked well in the mean time is add an explicit authorization header to the user/login request with a beanshell preprocessor to base64 encode the username / password.

thanks anyways